# not submit form of parent window when child window is open

Tags: javascript, php

I write this code..but i want to not submit form of parent window when child window is open

```
<script language="javascript">   
 function popwindow(page) { 
OpenWin = this.open(page,"CtrlWindow","top=80,left=100,screenX=100,screenY=80,width=600,height=400,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no, scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes");
OpenWin.focus();
return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a global variable with false and when you open the child/new window set it to true. on window close set that variable again to false. on form submit check that variable state. if it is false do submit otherwise don't submit. use **window.open/window.close** method for this.

Use this code:

HTML

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <button value="open" id="open">Open</button>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

JS (jQuery 1.9)

```
$(function(){
    var customWindow = false;
    $('#open').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        customWindow = true;
        customWindow = window.open('http://www.google.com', "","menubar=1,resizable=1"); 
        customWindow.focus(); 
    });

    $('[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(customWindow.closed || !customWindow) {
            alert('form submit');
        } else {
            alert('please close the child window');
        }
    });
});
```

[see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dk6mX/1/)

Comment: how to assign the variable??

Comment: shouldn't it either read `cusWindow = window.open( ...` or `customWindow.focus()`?

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand what's happening... Why do you set `customWindow = true;` if you're setting it to `window.open()`'s return value immediately afterwards? And wouldn't just `customWindow.closed` be sufficient later? Can `customWindow.closed` ever be false and `customWindow` also evaluate to false at the same time?

Comment: When the page start. customWindow is false so else statement executed for this I initialized it to true for first time.

Answer (score 0):

There's a  `closed` property with the window, so just check OpenWin.closed.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_closed.asp